# Why use the preposition "по" in "партнер по поединкам"?

Tags: предлоги

> партнер **по** поединкам

```
Context: The speaker was jokingly mentioning someone he often has spars with.
```

The *why* of using the preposition "по" does not come naturally to me: "a partner **for** quarrels"? Could it be that "партнер" often, if not always, takes "по" as a preposition?

As an aside: Does "партнер по поединку" in the dative singular work just as well?

Comment: "Поединок" is more like "fight" than "quarrel".

Answer (score 4):

One of the meanings the "по" conveys is "pertaining to". "Заседание по поводу [чего-то]" -- "meeting to discuss/celebrate [something]"; "работы по данной теме" -- "[scientific] works on this subject"; "сосед по [лестничной] площадке" -- "neighbour whose flat's located at the same [stairs] landing".

The aside: your case with dative singular wouldn't work, I think, you'd want "партнер/противник **в** поединке/игре" here.

Comment: "По" perfectly works with singular. "Партнер по поединку", "партнер по игре", "напарник по смене".

Comment: Yes, quite so, but not in this specific case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, партнёр is often followed by по:

- партнёр по бизнесу = business partner
- партнёр по танцам = dancing partner
- коллега по работе = work colleague

Singular (партнёр по поединку) would mean a partner just for the current round / fight, whereas партнёр по поединкам (plural) means a regular sparring partner.